# Dynamically select a base month and base Cost in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am struggling with selecting a base month and base cost in Power BI dax.
Let me elaborate, I have a table/matrix visual of Month and Cost

[image]

I want to dynamically be able to select any month with its cost as a base. For example, I select 202006 month and 136 cost as my base then I would like to divide the base cost by all the monthly cost as shown below:
[image]

Also I would like to dynamically select any base hence dynamically change the relative month.
How can I achieve this with DAX?

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate table with Month/Cost (without relationship to your current table model);
Add this new month or Cost to filter.

Inside measure create variable and get selectedvalue; Example:

```
BaseCost = SELECTEDVALUE('TableCopy'[Cost])

RelativeCost = 
var _BaseCost = SELECTEDVALUE('TableCopy'[Cost]) -- also as mesure from above [BaseCost]
return

DIVIDE( Selectedvalue('OrgTable'[Cost]), _BaseCost )
```